# More efficient jquery for bill estimator

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on a calculator to find extra charges based on bill cost. The basic idea is that if the bill is less than $200, there are set charges for different increments. If the bill is over $200, then the charge goes up 1.12 for every $50 of increase. I ended up manually writing out all the possibilities up to $400, but I'm not sure how high the bills can go, and regardless I feel like there has to be a better way to do this, especially the part where the value is being updated within each IF statement.

```
<fieldset><label>Costs</label><input type="text" id="systemSize"/></fieldset>

<fieldset><label>Average bill amount <input type="text" id="billAmount"/></fieldset>

<p class="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</p>

if(billAmount){
        if(billAmount<50){
            alert ("Bill amount is too low");
        }

        if(billAmount>=50 && billAmount <75){
            systemSizeNew = ("2.8");
            $("#systemSize").val(systemSizeNew);
        }

        if(billAmount>=75 && billAmount <100){
            systemSizeNew = ("3.36");
            $("#systemSize").val(systemSizeNew);
        }

        if(billAmount>=100 && billAmount <150){
            systemSizeNew = ("4.3");
            $("#systemSize").val(systemSizeNew);
        }

        if(billAmount>=150 && billAmount <200){
            systemSizeNew = ("5.32");
            $("#systemSize").val(systemSizeNew);
        }

        if(billAmount>=200 && billAmount <250){
            systemSizeNew = ("6.44");
            $("#systemSize").val(systemSizeNew);
        }

        if(billAmount>=250 && billAmount <300){
            systemSizeNew = ("7.56");
            $("#systemSize").val(systemSizeNew);
        }

        if(billAmount>=300 && billAmount <350){
            systemSizeNew = ("8.68");
            $("#systemSize").val(systemSizeNew);
        }

        if(billAmount>=350 && billAmount <400){
            systemSizeNew = ("9.80");
            $("#systemSize").val(systemSizeNew);
        }
       }
```

Comment: You could use `(billAmount - 50) / 50`.. for the cases when the bill amount is enough to calculate the extra charges.

Comment: My first thought was to create an array, mapping the thresholds to the new size.  Something like `[{ min: 0, max:50, size:0}, { min: 50, max:75, size:2.8}, ...]` and then your logic turns into finding the element where your amount is in between the min/max and using the size given.  This would be in the absence of a detectable pattern, however.

Answer (score 2):

First let's move all the logic to a separate function:

```
const chargePer50Increment = 1.12;
const chargeUpTo = {
    75: 2.8,
    100: 3.36,
    150: 4.3,
    200: 5.32
};    

function chargeForBill(amount) {
    if (amount < 50) {
        // or however else you want to handle it
        alert ("Bill amount is too low");

        return false;
    }

    for (var upTo in chargeUpTo) {
        if (amount < upTo) {
            return chargeUpTo[upTo];
        }
    }

    // at this point amount is >= 200 and upTo = 200

    const numOf50Increments = 1 + Math.floor((amount - upTo) / 50)); 

    return chargeUpTo[upTo] + numOf50Increments * chargePer50Increment;
}
```

Now all you are going to need to do is this:

```
$("#systemSize").val(chargeForBill(billAmount));
```

Comment: This worked really well, thanks! The only problem I'm running into is that if I enter a value and click submit, then change the value, the systemSize value does not change when I click submit again

Answer (score 0):

A version of what @dubstylee mentioned in the comments.

```js
document.querySelector('#amount').addEventListener('input', function(event){
  var value = event.target.value;
  
  if (value < 50) {
    console.log(0);
  } else if (value < 75) {
    console.log(2.8);
  } else if (value < 100) {
    console.log(3.36);
  } else if (value < 150) {
    console.log(4.3);
  } else {
    /*
      take the value and subtract 200
      get the max between this value and 0, so the value will not be negative
      get the floor of this so values such as 0.98
          becomes 0 and 3.78 becomes 3
      multiply this by 1.12 before adding it to the base 5.32
    */
  
    console.log(
      5.32 + (
        Math.floor(Math.max(0, value - 200) / 50) * 1.12
      )
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="amount" value="49" min="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases i would specify a dictionary which reflects the thresholds as keys (note that the order of defining the keys matters here - like arrays, dictionaries keep the order of their keys), and define a callback function, since you have different actions based on the bill amount (Otherwise it could be simply a value mapping for `#systemSize`)

```js
function setSystemSize(systemSize) {
  return () => $("#systemSize").val(systemSize);
}

let callbacks = {
  50: () => alert("Bill amount is too low"),
  75: setSystemSize('2.80'),
  100: setSystemSize('3.36'),
  150: setSystemSize('4.30'),
  200: setSystemSize('5.32'),
  250: setSystemSize('6.44'),
  300: setSystemSize('7.56'),
  350: setSystemSize('8.68'),
  Infinity: setSystemSize('9.80'),
}

$('button.submit').on('click', function() {
  let value = parseInt($('#billAmount').val(), 10);
  if(isNaN(value)) return alert('enter bill amount');
  callbacks[Object.keys(callbacks).find(k => value < Number(k))]();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <label>Costs <input type="text" id="systemSize" readonly></label>
  <br>
  <label>Average bill amount <input type="text" id="billAmount"></label>
  <br>
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
```